# SQL query for comparing two rows and getting the differences from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, compare, row

I want to compare the two rows of same ID and I just want to get difference as result.

e.g.

**NOW**

```
|---ID---||--Col_1--||--Col_2--||--Col_3--||--Col_4--|
|----1---||----2----||----4----||----5----||----6----|
|----1---||----3----||----4----||----4----||----6----|
|----2---||----2----||----3----||----3----||----2----|
```

**RESULT**

```
|---ID---||--Col_1--||--Col_2--||--Col_3--||--Col_4--|
|----1---||----3----||---NULL--||----4----||---NULL--|
```

**P.S : I'm using SQL Server 2012**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why you have chosen `3` for `col_1` and `4` for `Col_3` why not `5` for `Col_3`

Comment: You can create query for choosing `2` for `Col_1` and `5` for `Col_3`. I just want difference. @Prdp

Comment: Just replace Gordan's `case` statement with this `(case when min(col1) <> max(col1) then Max(col1) end)`

Comment: Worked like a charm... Thanks... @Prdp

Comment: @Prdp I believe that would give you a 5 in col_3, not a 4

Comment: @KevalPandya  Use `Union ALL`

Comment: I'm trying this `select (case when (EB.BIRTH_DATE) <> (B.BIRTH_DATE) then (EB.BIRTH_DATE) end) as BIRTH_DATE FROM BIRTH_ENTRY AS B INNER JOIN EDITED_BIRTH_ENTRY AS EB ON B.APPLICATION_NO = EB.APPLICATION_NO` But it doesn't work. Please help. @Prdp

Comment: @KevalPandya - Ask it as a new question with what you have tried

Comment: Website shows that I can only post after 90 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you want to combine the rows for the same id and apply the following rules:

- If the values are the same, then put the value in the row.
- If the values are different, then put in `NULL`.
- If there is only one row, then don't include the `id`.

This is an aggregation query with some filtering and comparison logic:

```
select id,
       (case when min(col1) = max(col1) then min(col1) end) as col1,
       . . .
from t
group by id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Wow, I am thinking of some complex join's

Comment: I guess you didn't get it. (1) If the values are the DIFFERENT, then put the value in the row. (2) If the values are the SAME, then put NULL. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @KevalPandya - Please read your question properly :D. You have kept `NULL` when values are different for same `ID`

Comment: ID's number remains constant. So that I can know what the row is. Change the other columns. @Prdp

Comment: Which number would you put if they are different? Plus your question literally shows the exact opposite

Comment: If difference is found, put 2nd row's value. @kbball

Comment: @KevalPandya - Dude, your question is shows exact opposite of what you are saying here in comments. Please edit the question atleast